# Is it okay to add read and execute permission to all files in /usr/bin and /usr/lib and local?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, bin

On a linux system, say Scientific Linux release 6.7 (Carbon)

Is it okay to do the following?

```
   chmod +R a+rx /usr/bin
   chmod +R a+rx /usr/lib
   chmod +R a+rx /usr/local/bin
   chmod +R a+rx /usr/local/lib
```

Because after using sudo install the installed package 
usually forbid permission to others/group, I would like
to know if the above practise is generally unharmful.
If not, what is the potential damage and how to fix it?

Comment: This may spark a nasty debate, but, doing what you suggest may open possibilities for either a clever intruder, or malware to run a muck; however, you can deny rx for other users than the expected user; which may be safer, but, if you're using the system as desktop your "video" and other "users" may become under-privileged.

Comment: why video and users might be under privileged?

Comment: Assumed you deny access for all other users after the chmod for security, but, you don't have to do that, it's up to you ;)

Comment: I'm afraid as you said that's too restrictive. I just checked another linux server and it seems that the files there are indeed set to be +rx already. Maybe to be cautious I should use find by modified time to chmod ...